# Get socket level errors from tornado HTTPClient

Tags: python, sockets, httpclient, tornado

Suppose that I have http server located at (host:port) and I'm trying to use HTTPClient example from the tornado docs to fetch some data from that server, so I have a code below

```
from tornado import httpclient

http_client = httpclient.HTTPClient()
try:
    response = http_client.fetch("http://host:port", connect_timeout=2)
    print response.body

except httpclient.HTTPError as e:
    print e.code
    print e.message

http_client.close()
```

This works fine and in case everything goes well (host is available, server is working, etc.) my client successfully receives data from the server. Now I want to handle errors that can occur during connection process and handle them depending on the error code. I'm trying to get error code by using e.code in my exception handler, but it contains HTTP error codes only and I need some lower level error codes, for instance:

1) If server is not avaliable on the destination host and port it prints out

```
599
HTTP 599: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

2) If it is impossible to reach the host (for example due to network connectivity problems), I receive the same HTTP 599 error code:

```
599
HTTP 599: [Errno 101] Connection refused
```

So I need to get Errno in my exception handler that would indicate actual lower level socket error and the only solution I see for now is to grep it from the text message I receive (e.message) but this solution looks rough and ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your only option is to pull it out of e.message:

```
import re
m = re.search( "\[Errno (\d+)\]", e.message)
if m:
    errno = m.group(1)
```

On my platform (Linux), I actually get a socket.gaierror exception when I take your code example and use a bogus URL, which provides direct access to errno. But if you're dealing with tornado.httpclient.HTTPError, I don't think there's any way for you to get at it directly.

Comment: For now (as of Tornado 3.2) parsing the error message is the best you can do for certain errors, but I'll try to fix that in a future release.  Note that you are not guaranteed to get an HTTPError; when this is fixed it will probably raise an IOError directly.  (if you were using curl_httpclient instead of simple_httpclient, you'd get a CurlError instead)